# XlsxWriter Column-Line Chart

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Is it possible to create a Column-Line Chart in Python using [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

Excel has an option to this but this module doesn't seem to.

Answer (score 4):

Mixed charts types aren't currently possible in XlsxWriter.

**Update:** As of version 0.6.8 of XlsxWriter, it is now possible to [create combined charts](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/working_with_charts.html#chart-combined-charts).

Comment: Then how to create the column-line chart ?
Any possible to override the xlsx-writer library.